# Can I find the name on this account

Tags: united-kingdom, banking, paycheck

My wages got put in to the wrong account the company I worked for sent me the account number and sort code but I carnt find the name on the account is there any way of doing this

Comment: I think you're going to need to put a bit more effort into your question; right now it's incoherent, and it's missing some important information.  Are you saying that your company made a direct deposit that went into an account that is not your own account, and told you the account number it was sent to, and you want to find out whose account it was put in?  If that's the case, I'd also include _why_ you feel you need that information.

Comment: Your employer should be able to reverse the transaction and correct it. What country are you in?

Comment: Yes joe you are correct but also to the case the company I was working for have said that it was I that rang them to change my bank details which I never yet when I went to the bank because I told them the exact amount that went in on that certain day they confirmed the payment had been made and that it was no longer in the account the following day I just wanted to no if this must be the account of someone I no ?? Help please

Comment: I am in the UK and don't no where I stand with this situation

Comment: I don't know UK laws/regulations/etc. on the matter.  In the US it would be the responsibility of the employer to put a trace on the deposit, and to eventually correct it, even if it were your fault for giving them the wrong information - see [this article](http://budgeting.thenest.com/happens-write-wrong-account-number-direct-deposit-33484.html) for example - but in the UK things might be different, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks joe that's helped a lot it would still be nice to no just who's bank the money did go in to just in case it's a friend that has betrayed me

Comment: Report it to the police. If what you say is true, someone has committed criminal fraud. The police will be able to determine who owns the bank account (but likely won't tell you).

Comment: In the UK, if money appears in a bank account due to someone else's error, it doesn't become the recipient's money to do with as they please.  See http://www.theguardian.com/money/blog/2013/feb/09/bank-error-your-favour-spending-it-theft .  (I know people who've been on both sending and receiving end of such mistakes and in both cases it was sorted out without too much trouble).  However given the comments above this does sound more like fraud.

Answer (score 7):

**This is not your problem and you should not try to fix it.**

If your employer paid money into someone else's account instead of yours they should ask their bank to reverse it and should pay you your wages while they are waiting for this to be done. No bank will let you do anything about money paid by someone else into an account that is not yours, or give you details of someone else's account.